# Automation of start/stop synapse trigger failed

Tags: triggers, azure-synapse

Service request failed while trying to start the synapse triggers through git hub workflow PowerShell script

the script can be able to find the triggers but it is unable to start the synapse trigger.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWezT.png)

im following the below post.
https://prashanth-kumar-ms.medium.com/how-to-start-and-stop-azure-synapse-triggers-using-github-actions-78ad9c08dd7a

Comment: From the error, it seems a pipeline connected to your trigger is missing in your destination environment.

Answer (score 0):

> missing or invalid pipeline references for trigger

Agreed with @Chen Hirsh, The above error cause because the trigger you are stating is not assigned with any pipeline.

If we navigate to Synapse workspace -> manage -> Triggers -> << your trigger name >> -> please look at the column "**related**" , it might be showing 0 if no pipeline in attached to it .

[image]

Please attach the existing pipeline to trigger then start it from PowerShell it will start it.